# How can I disable prompt about trust when encrypting file with gpg in emacs

Tags: emacs, encryption, gnupg, pgp

I want to use emacs to edit files encrypted with gnu privacy guard. Im using the gpg support built into emacs 23 which I think is easy pg assistant. I import keys created at the command line with `M-x epa-import-keys`. When I save a file with suffix .gpg I first get to choose recipients among the keys installed on my computer. I choose one of them, my own key created by myself. I then get the question: `Use untrusted key anyway? (y or n)`. What does this mean and how can I disable it? gpg works fine from the command line.

Versions: gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.9, emacs 23.3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Works fine now, here's what I did:

1. On the command line: I used `gpg --edit-key`, and then changed the trust level of my key to the highest level.
2. In Emacs: I changed the `epg-gpg-home-directory` variable to the .gnupg directory holding my gpg key.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `epg-gpg-home-directory`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use any of "sign" options with edit-key